# How to convert all lists to sets when json file is loaded

Tags: python, json

I have json files that look like this:

```
{
    "K1": {
        "p": [
            "A"
        ], 
        "s": [
            "B", 
            "C"
        ]
    }, 
    "K2": {
        "p": [
            "A", 
            "F"
        ], 
        "s": [
            "G", 
            "H",
            "J"
        ]
    }
}
```

I can easily read in this data:

```
import json

with open('json_lists_to_sets.json') as fi:
    data = json.load(fi)
```

Then `data` looks as follows:

```
{u'K2': {u'p': [u'A', u'F'], u's': [u'G', u'H', u'J']}, u'K1': {u'p': [u'A'], u's': [u'B', u'C']}}
```

For my further analysis, however, it would be better to use `sets` instead of `lists`. I can of course convert `lists` to `sets` after I have read in the data:

```
for vi in data.values():
    vi['p'] = set(vi['p'])
    vi['s'] = set(vi['s'])
```

which gives me the desired output:

```
print data['K2']
```

yields

```
{u'p': {u'A', u'F'}, u's': {u'G', u'H', u'J'}}
```

My questions is whether I can convert these `lists` to `sets` directly when I read in the data in the `json.load` command, so something like "convert all lists you find to sets". Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the `json` library offers many hooks to alter decoding, there is no hook to hook into loading a JSON array.

You'll have to recursively update the decoded result afterwards instead:

```
def to_sets(o):
    if isinstance(o, list):
        return {to_sets(v) for v in o}
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: to_sets(v) for k, v in o.items()}
    return o
```

This handles lists at any nested dictionary depth:

```
>>> to_sets(data)
{u'K2': {u'p': set([u'A', u'F']), u's': set([u'H', u'J', u'G'])}, u'K1': {u'p': set([u'A']), u's': set([u'C', u'B'])}}
```

Take into account however, that lists containing other dictionaries *can't* be handled because dictionaries are not hashable.

If you expect to find lists nested inside other lists, you'd have to switch to using a `frozenset()` rather than a `set()` to be able to nest those:

```
def to_sets(o):
    if isinstance(o, list):
        return frozenset(to_sets(v) for v in o)
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: to_sets(v) for k, v in o.items()}
    return o
```

Comment: Works fine, upvoted. There won't be any nested list but thanks for mentioning the `frozenset` part; have not heard about this before.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the one liner expression to achieve this using `dict comprehension`:

```
>>> {key: {k: set(v) for k, v in nested_dict.items()} for key, nested_dict in data.items()}
{'K2': {'s': {'H', 'G', 'J'}, 'p': {'A', 'F'}}, 'K1': {'s': {'B', 'C'}, 'p': {'A'}}}
```

However, in case you want achieve it using `loop`, below is the example:

```
data = {u'K2': {u'p': [u'A', u'F'], u's': [u'G', u'H', u'J']}, u'K1': {u'p': [u'A'], u's': [u'B', u'C']}}
for key, nested_dict in data.items():
    data[key] = {k: set(v) for k, v in nested_dict.items()}

# Value of 'data': {'K2': {'s': {'H', 'G', 'J'}, 'p': {'A', 'F'}}, 'K1': {'s': {'B', 'C'}, 'p': {'A'}}}
```